# ajax upload não passa variáveis

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Não estou conseguindo passar as variáveis no método ajax.

```
<input type="file" id="id-input-file-2" name="arquivo" class="form-control arquivo" />
<input type="hidden" name="ID_Cotacao" id="ID_Cotacao" value="555">
```

.

```
$(function(){
    $('.arquivo').change(function(e){
        if ($('.arquivo').val() != "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('arquivo', $('.arquivo').prop('files')[0]);
            formData.append('nomeArquivo', $('.arquivo').val());
            formData.append('id_cotacao', $('#ID_Cotacao').val());

            $.ajax({
                url: 'cotacoesEditarUpload.php',
                data: formData,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(){
                    alert("Enviado com sucesso."),
                    $(".listaArquivo").load(window.location + " .listaArquivo")
                },
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Como aparece no console do navegador:
**cotacoesEditarUpload.php?[object FormData]&_=1441423098339**

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: @Brunno não deu certo. Mesmo problema.

Comment: vamos ter que esperar alguém que mexa com php pra te ajudar :PP só dei um palpite azedo hahaha' :DD

Comment: Valeu bruno, muito obrigado pela dica. Se tiver outra vou ficar feliz em testar :)

Comment: Alguma luz no fim do túnel?

Comment: @Brunno assim funcionou as variáveis `data: 'arquivo'+ $('.arquivo').prop('files')[0] +'&nomeArquivo='+ $('.arquivo').val() +'&id_cotacao='+ $('#ID_Cotacao').val(),` mas o arquivo não é enviado, somente as variáveis. Sabe como fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Estou assumindo que você quer fazer um upload de arquivo.

Upload de arquivo não pode ser realizado em uma requisição `GET`. Não que seja impossível (seria necessário ler os dados do arquivo e codificá-los em algo como base64 ou alguma outra representação que possa ser colocada em uma query HTTP).

Utilize para fazer upload de arquivo o método `POST` ou o `PUT`. Do lado do servidor, cada um deles possui particularidades no processamento dos dados, sendo o `POST` mais tradicional especialmente se utiliza PHP.

Com exceção do método da requisição, não vejo outro problema no seu código interferindo no envio do `FormData`.

Trecho do código:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'cotacoesEditarUpload.php',
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(){
```